# grep exact string by pattern in variable

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, match

I want to grep exact string by pattern in variable

```
ip="192.168.100.1"
arp -a | grep "$ip"
```

This outputs something like this:

```
# arp -a | grep "$ip"
? (192.168.10.1) at 66:ca:6d:88:57:cd [ether]  on br0
? (192.168.10.15) at 3c:15:a0:05:b5:94 [ether]  on br0
```

but I want exactly IP no IP of other PCs
Also I have only embedded grep (minimalistic) also I have awk,sed.

Im trying this but without success:

```
arp -a | grep "\b$ip\b"
```

Comment: `arp -a | grep -o "$ip"`

Comment: That grep will NOT produce that output. [edit] your question to correct your example.

Answer (score 1):

Word boundaries like `\b` aren't available with standard grep. From the output snippet you posted it looks like this will work for you:

```
$ ip="192.168.10.1"
$ grep -F "($ip)" file
? (192.168.10.1) at 66:ca:6d:88:57:cd [ether]  on br0
```

i.e. just use `-F` for a string instead of regexp comparison and explicitly include the delimiters that appear around the IP address in the input.

FWIW in awk it'd be:

```
$ awk -v ip="($ip)" 'index($0,ip)' file
? (192.168.10.1) at 66:ca:6d:88:57:cd [ether]  on br0
```

and you can't do it in a reasonable way in sed since sed ONLY supports regexp comparisons, not strings (see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460)).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are saying you just want to add a `-o` option to your command, the `-o` option print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,with each such part on a separate output line.

```
arp -a | grep -o "$ip"
```